# How to create tables as follows and how to add data with PHP to those tables?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create tables and add the data with PHP as follows:

#### USER TABLES

- **Table A** - ID + Name
- **Table B** - ID + Value A + Value B + IDTable A

I want to put the user details to table B and the same User ID + Name to separate tables. How can I do that? How do I write the SQL in PHPMyAdmin?

Also, I need to make a table where a user can add friends. I don't have a clue how to make this, but if you have any suggestions please let me know. It's for a small social app I'm developing on android.

Thank you.

Comment: If I understand you right, you need to look into `views` for this one.

Comment: Really? how come i cannot have two tables for users?

Comment: Ok, after the edit it made more sense. Of course you can make as many tables as you want to ( although I wouldn't practise it myself ). In this case, just make two tables and `JOIN` them on sql request.

Comment: Ouch, in that case http://eu.dummies.com/DummiesTitle/productCd-0470096004.html

Comment: the thing is i know how to create two separate tables but do not know how to create two tables with unique ID... simple as that

Answer (score 1):

So this isn't going to be a simple one size fits all answer, it would be best if you understood what you were doing. You are going to need to make sql queries using PHP.

**EDIT:** I may have misunderstood your question, I apologize. From what I understand you are trying to find a way to link Table A to Table B using the ID tag (so that the ID for a single user extends across multiple tables). The way I would approach this is through the use of a Primary Key. Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE TableA(
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    NAME VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE TableB(
    B_ID INT NOT NULL,
    VALUE A ####,
    VALUE B ####,
    A_ID INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(B_ID)
);
```

Whenever you add a value to TableB also add the primary key `ID` from `TableA` that the data belongs to. In the above example `####` is NOT sql syntax it represents whatever datatype you want to store in those values as it was not specified in your question.

The question that this leads to is are you trying to allow multiple entries from the same user ID into TableB (i.e. A_ID=5 shows up several times in TableB)? If so this is as far as you can bring your database scheme from what I know. If there will only be one entry in TableB for every entry in TableA you should instead make A_ID the  Primary Key in TableB and get rid of B_ID as it will be redundant.

If this does not fully answer your question, please leave a comment below explaining what you still don't understand and what you need help with. If my answer is no where close to answering your question, please edit/reword your question so that we may provide you with better answers.

Cheers and happy coding!

Comment: Indeed going back to school on this one will help.

Comment: sorry mate... all new to me since i just began. i know the concept but on hand i have no experience. well thnx, its better if u can tell me how to create these two tables